# Recursion Infinite loop in java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a recursive method that I am trying to complete. Where it adds the elements in an array in a balanced way in a Binary Search Tree.

```
public void addBalanced(String file){
    addToArrayList(file);
    addBalanced(a,0, a.size()-1);
}
 private void addBalanced(ArrayList<String> list,int start, int end){
     int middle = (start+end)/2;
     bst.add(list.get(middle));
     if(list.size() == 0){
         return;
     }else if (list.size() == 1){
         bst.add(a.get(0));
     } else if(start >= end){
         return;
     }
     addBalanced(list,start, middle-1);
     addBalanced(list,middle+1, end);

 }
```

The variable a is the array list that is et to the number of lines that the file consists of
 The variable BST is a binary search tree

It is in an infinite loop that I can tell and not sure how to fix it. I tried adding a base case for array with size 0 and 1, but it is still stuck in the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BSTSpellChecker<String> foo = new BSTSpellChecker<>();
    foo.addBalanced(foo.getFilePath());

}
```

This is the test text file:

a
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aardvark
aardvarks
aardwolf
ab
abaci
aback
abacus
abacuses
abaft
abalon

Comment: post the test case that results in the infinite loop

Comment: It never stops running. I had it run for like 10 minutes straight with no result with a file with 15 words.

Comment: yes. so post the test case. see http://sscce.org/

Comment: What is `bst`, what is `a`? Do you name the same data structure `bst`, `list` and `a` in `addBalanced`?

Comment: If the list (named a) has an initial size of 1, infinite loop, no return possible

Comment: I fixed the loop problem but now I have a null pointer exception from the array that I have set to the number of lines that the file consist of. I don't understand how I have an array with all the available slots in the array taken up and have a null pointer exception.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512230/recursion-infinite-loop-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the initial size of `list` is `1` it will never stop

`List` is not changed inside the method. So it's size cannot be zero. If it's size is 1, second `else if` block executes every time, not goes to third one